# How to detect misspelled words in Google Docs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-docs-api

Google Docs already marks misspelled words with a red underline. My question is whether **is there is a Google provided API that I can use to loop through misspelled words.**

I search for quite sometime, but had hard time to find one.

Comment: There are no built-in methods. However, you can post to and receive data from external services (e.g. sending the text for spell-checking). The UI can be built using sidebars and dialogs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently not supported by Google APIs like docs or apps script that's why you never found any details.